# How to use SQL Server CE table indexing - is it worth doing for this query?

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-ce

Been a learning process and I finally managed to get a query that runs for SQL Server Compact Edition.

My initial problem remains, and that is how to improve performance. A couple people commented that I should try to index my query so that is what I am looking at now.

This query will take all players at one school that belong to one weight, and select the highest skill amongst them and set that players starter value equal to true.

```
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE player " &
            "SET starter = 'TRUE' " &
            "WHERE NOT EXISTS" &
            "(SELECT school, weight, skill " &
            "FROM player b " &
            "WHERE b.school = player.school " &
            "AND b.weight = player.weight " &
            "AND b.skill > player.skill)"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The query runs extremely slow.

- My 'player' table has ~170,000 players
- Each player belongs to one of 4500 schools
- Each player belongs to one of 14 weights
- Each school belongs to one of 50 states

Is there any way I can index this query to make it run faster? Or what can I do because right now the amount of time is takes to run this query is crazy.

If it helps explain what I am working with I will provide an image of the player table. (The ID and firstName are not shown)

http://i44.tinypic.com/jkygcp.png

Thanks!

@rob - This is the query as I have it typed in my program.

```
        cmd.CommandText = "update p1 " &
                    "set starter = 'TRUE' " &
                    "from player as p1 " &
                    "left outer join player as p2 " &
                    "on p1.school = p2.school " &
                    "and p1.weight = p2.weight " &
                    "and p1.playerId <> p2.playerId " &
                    "and p1.skill <= p2.skill " &
                    "where(p2.playerId Is null)"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with Nathaniel Ford that the first step is probably to rewrite the query a bit, but I might suggest a different direction (which might or might not work out).

I think your goal is to mark the "best" player at each school in each weight category as the starter.  I also think you only want to mark this starter if there is a clear best (skill strictly greater than everyone in the school/weight).  I might not have that last criteria correct... as it could leave some school/weights without a marked starter (easily fixed with a second query of similar form).

This sort of "best of a group" query be expressed neatly using windowing functions, but I don't think SQL Compact supports those.  You could express it as an *anti-join*.  It's weird, but can help suggest an index.

```
update p1
set starter = 'TRUE'
from player as p1
left outer join player as p2
   on p1.school = p2.school
  and p1.weight = p2.weight
  and p1.playerId <> p2.playerId
  and p1.skill <= p2.skill
where p2.playerId is null
```

We're updating `p1`.  Let's try to join as `p2` all the players in the same school/weight as `p1` that are are as good or better than `p1` (and let's exclude the player in `p1` that we're talking about since everyone is as good as himself).  If we find someone that is as good or better, then `p1` is *not* a starter.  However, if we can't find anyone as good or better, which means the `left outer join` will leave `p2.playerId` NULL, then we have the best choice for that school/weight and should mark `p1` as the starter.  (That paragraph was a little loose; I hope it was clear.)

Anti-joins are a way to express not exists queries.  I think the optimizer can rewrite some or all "not exists" queries as anti-joins.  The point here though was to suggest an index (and maybe help the optimizer if it missed this trick).

If that query does what you want, and works on SQL Compact (which I don't have access to), and actually is right (again - zero testing), then you might think about an index something like this:

```
create index player_i01 on player ( school, weight, skill, playerId )
```

If none of these things get you the performance that you want, then consider building a work table (perhaps a temporary table) to divide the work.  I'll save that for another answer... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This forum is really quite helpful. Unfortunately that query does not work in the compact edition I am using. Get an error parsing the query. Turns out temp tables are not supported either... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/22cad58d-ff6c-4a32-82ef-75482ec175fb/                                                        I am starting to feel severely limited with this piece of software lol :(

Comment: I don't use CE, but I thought it understood outer joins.  What was the parse error?  Oh, and even without temp tables you can still create a "work" table - just a regular table that you use as a work area.

Comment: Been busy for a few days. I created the index like you showed. What do I need to do to utilize the indexing? And as far as the work table, should I be having columns [playerId][weight][skill] and then just load the table with players from school X, find the starters, set them in the original table and repeat? I guess I am a little confused. Thanks!

Comment: @Meowbits Were you able to get the update statement above to work?  After creating the index, do `UPDATE STATISTICS ON player`.  Using a work table is a slightly different approach...  I'll write that up as another answer.

Comment: No I was not able to get it to run. Parsing error. The original one that I posted runs, that is the only query I have been able to "use" so far. When I try to execute the update statistics I have an error "FULLSCAN option is required for CREATE/UPDATE STATISTICS"

Comment: @Meowbits Here's the doc for statistics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174025.aspx

Comment: @Meowbits Do you get more info about the parse error?  Where in the statement is the error?

Comment: Thanks, I created the update. The parsing error I have is [link](http://tinypic.com/r/ml2r9l/5) and I updated my original post at the bottom to show the exact text I am using to run your query.

Comment: @Meowbits Oh, I did not realize that compact didn't understand update with a from clause... but it doesn't.  (It's non-standard, but sql server supports it.)

Comment: Right, best to use the original then you think?

Comment: More than me ;) Is there anything else I need to do with the indexing?

Comment: I'm out of CE suggestions...  If I think of anything I'll start a new answer.

Comment: You know what? I think it is working. And it is working fast ;) Less than a minute to run it now. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the code you're executing to run the sql is confusing matters somewhat. I've restated it below:

```
UPDATE player SET starter = 'TRUE' WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT school, weight, skill 
    FROM player b 
   WHERE b.school = player.school 
     AND b.weight = player.weight 
     AND b.skill > player.skill
)
```

Let's first look at the inner select statement. This statement is essentially asking for a result table with three columns (school, weight, skill) from a table 'player'. You alias this table as 'b'. You then go on to filter by three things; whether b.school is equivalent to player.school and so on.

Your first problem is that based on your alias, b.school = player.school is equivalent to player.school=player.school. For your first two filters, all rows will be selected - this is unnecessary calculation. Your final filter, however, should always return false, and that is why your query is taking so long in all likelihood: all rows will be returned from your inner select statement.

Assuming, in the outer statement, you alias player to be, say, a, then you're going to get a separate result, because you're now asking if player a is at the same school, has the same weight and is better. (1) In this case, though, what you're doing is comparing every player against every other player: for 170,000 players that is 170k^2 or roughly 39 billion comparisons... which is why this query is so slow.

There are two ways of solving your problem. The first is to handle some of this programmaticly.

1. select all unique schools as a query
2. for each school, run a similar query

The other is to do a clever sql join. Here I use 'playerId' as some column that is a unique identifier. (Hopefully your table has one.) (2)

```
SELECT a.playerId 
  FROM player a INNER JOIN player b
    ON ( a.school = b.school AND a.weight = b.weight)
 WHERE a.skill > b.skill
```

By using the built-in join functionality (3) this query should run a lot faster and result in a table of all match-ups possible (only players at the same school and in the same weight), which is then filtered by skill. The original result table, pre-filter, will be much smaller than what you were working with.

One last thing; using 'not exists' is pretty kludgey and may be impacting your performance. Try something like;

```
UPDATE player c SET starter = 'TRUE' WHERE c.player IN
(
  SELECT a.playerId 
    FROM player a INNER JOIN player b
      ON ( a.school = b.school AND a.weight = b.weight)
   WHERE a.skill > b.skill
)
```

(1) note: it is possible in some sql implementations that the 'player' in the inner statement will be interpreted as the 'player' in the outer statement, but I'm not sure if that is guaranteed. Therefore you should alias it to be sure.

(2) I am not 100% this will work, because I don't have your table to play with.

(3) SQL Servers are generally built to make this stuff fast. But you have to know how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed post. I tried to use that query and due to some limitations (I think) for sql compact, it would not run. I may have to go program a couple different queries at this point. Would that bring the running time down to something not so insanely long?

Comment: @Nathaniel I think your last query isn't quite right --- that or I don't understand the desired outcome.  Let's imagine there is only one school and one weight (so my example fits in a comment), and that there are three players (1,2,3) that have skills (1,2,3).  I think your inner select would produce three rows, (1), (1), (2).  This is because 1 > 2, and 1 > 3, and 2 > 3.  Again, I might be way off base here --- it is a little late in the evening for me.

Answer (score 1):

For general tutorial on the topic of indexing and performance, I warmly recommend reading: [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com).

In this particular case, you'd want to enable the DBMS to efficiently determine the (non)existence of row(s) fulfilling the criteria under your query's `WHERE` clause. I'm not too familiar with the SQL Server Compact, but on most DBMSes the **composite** index on `{school, weight, skill}` in table `player` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The first place to look for index-related improvements is in join and where clauses.  I expect a complex clustered key on state, weight and school (in the players table) would create some noticeable improvement.

I'd also suggest adding an autoincrement 'Row Identifier' column to your player table.  Put a non-clustered primary key index on this table.  Then update your table to use the new primary key field in your query:

```
WHERE b.RowId = player.RowId
```

Comment: I will look into implementing this. Do you mean to have an additional row that would be for example 1-200 if there were 200 players at school X and repeat for every new school?

Comment: Actually, I mean an additional *column* in the player table that would have an autoincrementing value (I see I mis-typed as autoindex and I'll edit to fix that).  This small integer value uniquely identifies the row and provides a small-footprint unique index.

Comment: Was a little busy with other things the last couple days. Anyway, I do have a primary key [ID] which is a number 1-172000(auto increment) to identify every player. This column did not fit in the picture I posted. I stated this but I could have done a better job of explaining it. Sorry if I caused any confusion. I think for now I will look into creating a work table like Rob mentioned and indexing based on school,weight,skill,player (If that makes sense)